# Share a link from Android App using facebook-android-sdk with local image

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.x

My android application using facebook-android-sdk:4.14.0 to share a link. I used ShareLinkContent to create share content and call setImageUrl() to specify image. I want to use image from my app (not from a internet url link) to show on share post. I already tried as below code but it not work:

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("...")
            .setContentDescription("...")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://...))
            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/ic_boxworldpro.png"))
            .build();

    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainMenuActivity.this, "Unable to Share...Try again.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I also tried with image from drawable but the phenomenon was same

```
.setImageUrl(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.ic_boxworldpro))
```

Anyone can help me !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the document [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

`setImageUrl` should use a `URL`, not a uniformed `Uri` in Android platform.

> a imageURL, the URL of thumbnail image that will appear on the post

Also the java docs of the library has clearly say `A network URL of image`

```
public ShareLinkContent.Builder setImageUrl(@android.support.annotation.Nullable android.net.Uri imageUrl)
Set the URL of a picture to attach to this content.
Parameters:
    imageUrl - The network URL of an image.
Returns:
    The builder.
```

Comment: It mean that i must specify the URL via internet of an image to setImageUrl. It can not be the internal application image ?

Comment: @tuanpm No. The image should be located in `Network`. You can upload your photo to a photo service provider or to your own server, then use it.